# How do I get the Windows driver for an Atheros AR5001+?

Tags: windows, drivers, wireless-networking

I can only find drivers as far back as 5002 on the Atheros website. Google pointed me to [this site](http://www.atheros.cz/), but it's not in English and I find figure out how to download from it. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm looking for the Windows XP driver. I dual-boot with XP and Ubuntu. In XP, only wired works right now. In Ubuntu, both wired and wireless work fine out of the box.

Also, this is an external card, branded as netgear--it did not come with the laptop.

Comment: What OS by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the driver](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/875) through Netgear's website.

Comment: Which is the first place you should always look.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded from that site before. The problem isn't so much that it's not in english as they hide the links behind javascript functions. The download link doesn't indicate when you mouseover. Also, their download server seems to be down at the moment -- I tried downloading from 2 different internet connections, without success. But, like I said, I have downloaded from there before successfully.

Most of the other driver sites are even spammier though. No chance to download from the company that included the Atheros chip?

Comment: I bought the Wireless card in a store. It's an external card made by Netgear, since the laptop didn't come with a card built-in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://support.dell.com/support/index.aspx
2. Click on "Drivers and Downloads".
3. Pick the driver from the list (I forgot which one it was).

Comment: I unaccepted this answer, because it turns out it didn't work after all. I thought it did, but it really just fixed my wired connection.